# value not getting from index view to controller method in asp.net mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

As i showing the list of records in the index view in my asp.net mvc 2 + C# application. on the edit link, I am passing the string value which is the primary key in the db. so that I can access the respective records. but as i set the debugger at the controller in the Edit method , in parameter list I am not getting the value that I have passed. Scenario is like this :

INDEX : View

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.CRNo }) %>
```

In CONTROLLER:

```
public ActionResult Edit(String CRNo) // Here getting null
    {...some code...}
```

Where CRNo is string property of item.

Comment: Please help me over this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `id` as a parameter in the link, so you should read that.

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
```

Comment: Thanks , Its working. I have to use CRNo insteed of id . thanks.